# Pug sheds too much fur

Tags: dogs

I have a one year old pug. He sheds too much fur to the extent that I can see his hairs all around my apartment. He absolutely hates being brushed.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried desensitizing your dog to brushing?  High praise with very short brushing sessions in the order of one or two strokes.  Followed by maybe some belly rubs and treats?  Do this slowly over the course of several days and build up to where your dog associates the brush and being brushed with something they enjoy.  Doing so now can save you lots of time and prevent the grooming struggles that a lot of dog owners face later on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered other products besides a brush like [this one](http://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/product/four-paws-magic-coat-red-pet-love-glove)?  It's possible that the brush may be painful to your pug, making him dislike it.  Using something like the above link is essentially petting them while at the same time getting the loose hair off them.

If you suspect that your dog is losing too much fur, I would try changing to a different type of food - one that improves hair.